# Script for adding same id to all tables automatically

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a web site with lot of  tables , now for using a specific script, requires an ID for each table, is there a method for adding  same id on every table in website automatically ?

example by default the table s is this:

```
<table class="table-cr">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

after :

```
<table id="xxxx" class"table-cr">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#XXXX");
    });
</script>

Comment: Could pls explain its clearly wat's your problem ?

Comment: i want use a http://johnpolacek.github.io/stacktable.js/ script for make the table responsive , this script require a id table, now my site not have a id for every table, so i request if it's possible use a script to add on every table a specific id so, after this the script make responsive the table

Comment: the point of an id on an html element is to be unique. If multiple tables have the same id strange behavior will happen, and the library probably will not work any better.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a possible solution:

Iterate through the tables in the page and assign the id as shown below,

```js
var tables = $('table');
$.each(tables, function(i, tbl){
  $(tbl).prop('id', 'table'+i);     
});

$('#status').text('Dynamic Id of third table is: '+$(tables[2]).prop('id'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table-cr">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill1</td>
    <td>Smith1</td> 
    <td>501</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve1</td>
    <td>Jackson1</td> 
    <td>941</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="table-cr">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill2</td>
    <td>Smith2</td> 
    <td>502</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve2</td>
    <td>Jackson2</td> 
    <td>942</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="table-cr">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill3</td>
    <td>Smith3</td> 
    <td>503</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve33</td>
    <td>Jackson3</td> 
    <td>943</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<label id='status'/>
```

Comment: thanks , but show different id for every table, i want use the same id

Comment: it is not a good practice to have same id for all the tables. Why do you want to assign same id for the tables?

Comment: Exactly ^ - use a class instead. @themich

Comment: is not a problem because in a single page compare a single table, i want use a single id because with stacktable.js  requre declare a script for every id , so if id is one the cose the reduce to a siple line

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it using javascript as

```
document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].setAttribute("id", "demoid");
```

this code will simply add the id ***demoid*** to your table

Answer (score 0):

Can you try,Every time id of the table has been run when page load

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function () { $("#XXXX"); }); 
  </script>
```

Comment: *"can you try"* type of answers are fit more as a comment, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: use 4 spaces (or more) followed by code, or highlight code then do CTRL-K to properly indent. I edited your code.

Comment: not understand this script . i have tested but not work

Comment: Just the table has been load in script when the page load.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I did not understand what you mean, you can give an example

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution

```
$(function () {
  $('table').each(function (i, t) {
     $(t).prop('id', 'table');
  });
});
```

Comment: this work, add id on table, but  not work with stacktable.js,

Comment: stacktable.js  work with your code only if send with chrome console after load page the script  $('#table').stacktable({myClass:'small-only'});, if insert this code in php page not work after load page.

Comment: @themich of course it does not work, ids are supposed to be **unique**. If you have the same id multiple times, it breaks the behavior.

Comment: @felix is right. just add $(t).prop('id','table'+i);

Comment: @ Félix Gagnon-Grenier , i don't have multiple id, in a page compare only a 1 table(1 id), the problem is if load in php page the script not function, if load from chrome console work, i tested also with $(t).prop('id','table'+i);, but never, this is a code $('#table0').stacktable({myClass:'small-only'});